# Project with path ':produit' could not be found in root project 'application', with a gradle multi-module project using Quarkus

Tags: gradle, quarkus

I'm trying to setup a Gradle multi-modules project that will use Quarkus to run the application.
My project structure is as follow

```
rootFolder    
|----produit    
|------build.gradle
|----application
|------build.gradle
|--settings.gradle
```

The root's `settings.gradle`:

```
rootProject.name = "proddoc"

include("produit")
include("application")


pluginManagement {
    val quarkusPluginVersion: String by settings
    val quarkusPluginId: String by settings
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        mavenLocal()
    }
    plugins {
        id(quarkusPluginId) version quarkusPluginVersion
    }
}
```

The `produit/build.gradle`:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.7.21"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

val quarkusPlatformVersion: String by project

dependencies {
    testImplementation(kotlin("test"))

    implementation(enforcedPlatform("io.quarkus:quarkus-vertx:${quarkusPlatformVersion}"))
    implementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-vertx")
}

tasks.test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

The `application/build.gradle` (generated using the Quarkus CLI):

```
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.7.22"
    kotlin("plugin.allopen") version "1.7.22"
    id("io.quarkus")
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}

val quarkusPlatformGroupId: String by project
val quarkusPlatformArtifactId: String by project
val quarkusPlatformVersion: String by project

dependencies {
    implementation(enforcedPlatform("${quarkusPlatformGroupId}:${quarkusPlatformArtifactId}:${quarkusPlatformVersion}"))
    implementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-reactive")
    implementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-kotlin")
    implementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-vertx")
    implementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jackson")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    implementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-arc")
    testImplementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-junit5")
    testImplementation("io.rest-assured:rest-assured")

    implementation(project(":produit")) // I just added this
}

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    systemProperty("java.util.logging.manager", "org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager")
}
allOpen {
    annotation("javax.ws.rs.Path")
    annotation("javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped")
    annotation("io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTest")
}

tasks.withType<org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_17.toString()
    kotlinOptions.javaParameters = true
}
```

The project compiles when I run a `gradle compileJava` at the project's root, however when I run a `quarkus dev` in the `application` directory, I have the following error:

> Project with path ':produit' could not be found in root project 'application'.

I don't know how to make the Quarkus project discover the module outside what it considers to be it's root directory. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is pretty simple:
Do not try to run the project (`./gradlew quarkusDev`) from the application folder but run it from the root's folder

However, an issue remains, related to this issue: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/30748
Quarkus doesn't detect the beans in the `produit` module in dev mode, but it works fine once the project packaged as a jar.